# Get unique/latest value from observable in component class (result of store selector)

Tags: angular, ngrx

My application is using Angular and ngrx store.
I am using a selector in the store to get the username property of the app state in my component constructor:

*test-component.ts*

```
export class TestComponent {
    username$: Observable<string>;
    constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.AppState>) {
        this.username$ = this.store.select(fromRegistration.getUsername);
    }

    testMethod() {
         //I need the value of the username observable here as a string
    }

}
```

This is working fine. 
I need to print the username in the component's template, which I am doing by using the async pipe:

*test-component.html*

```
<div>
{{username | async}}
</div>
```

This is also working correctly.

Now, I need to call a service from a method in TestComponent that sends the username as an argument. How can I achieve this? Do I need to stop using the async pipe and subscribe to the selector to then assign the username property (which would then be declared as a string) to the value of the observable?

To note: the username observable will only have 1 value, once I get 1 value I can stop watching it.

I understand by using the async pipe the component unsubscribe from the username observable automatically, when does this happen and how does the component knows I don't need to watch it anymore?

If I can't use the async pipe, how and when do I unsubscribe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually go with  [Maciej Treder's First thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877664/get-unique-latest-value-from-observable-in-component-class-result-of-store-sele#48880907) as I try to use dumb components whenever possible, but in some cases when I need the new value from a selector to perform extra stuff inside my component that I'm going to async pipe it to my template anyway (so I don't need any subscribing), I simply use rxjs **tap** operator which is the [pipeable operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) name of [**do**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html). So I replace this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selected$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromItems.getSelectedBrand));
}
```

By this:

```
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

ngOnInit() {
  this.selected$ = this.store.pipe(
    select(fromItems.getSelectedBrand),
    tap((brand: Brand) => {
      /**
       * do logic here
       */
    })
  );
}
```

Now if for some reasons you do need to subscribe to it without async piping it to any template as done in [Maciej Treder's second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877664/get-unique-latest-value-from-observable-in-component-class-result-of-store-sele#48880907), I'd suggest using `ngOnDestroy` to unsubscribe from it. You'll find more about it here:

- [How to unsubscribe from ngrx/store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496383/how-to-unsubscribe-from-ngrx-store)
- [When to Unsubscribe in Angular](https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3) - by Netanel Basal

Answer (score 2):

### First thought

The best way to solve this problem in your case would be create  a component input variable and pass it asynchronously from parent.

```
export class TestComponent {
    @Input()
    username: string;

    testMethod() {
         //I need the value of the username observable here as a string
    }

}
```

And here's how parent component should look:

```
@Component({
     template: '<test-component [username]="username$ | async">'
})
export class ParentComponent {
    username$: Observable<string>;
    constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.AppState>) {
        this.username$ = this.store.select(fromRegistration.getUsername);
    }
}
```

### Another solution

You can also set up local variable in your child component:

```
export class TestComponent {
    usernameString: string
    username$: Observable<string>;
    constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.AppState>) {
        this.username$ = this.store.select(fromRegistration.getUsername);
        this.username$.subscribe(name -> this.usernameString = name);
    }

    testMethod() {
        if (this.usernameString != undefined) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```